# Android - Background audio service force closed

Tags: android

I am developing an audio streaming app for android devices and I have some issues about the handling of background audio service.

The expected behaviour of my app is that the audio source will be played continuously, even if the device is in stand-by mode with the screen off, but sometimes the background audio service is interrupted without any apparent reason.

To fix this problem, I have started the service with the option START_STICKY.

In this way, the service will be restarted even if it is closed for any reason, but now I can't close the service with a force close of the app and sometimes the service it will be restarted even if I want to close it!

Does anyone can suggest me a correct way to handle this job?

---

Here is my code:

At first I have declared the intent in the **MainActivity**:

```
Intent playbackServiceIntent;
```

Inside the **onCreate()** method of the **MainActivity** I have registered the service:

```
playbackServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BackgroundAudioService.class);
```

To start the audio service through the **play button**:

```
startService(playbackServiceIntent);
```

To stop the service through the **stop button**

```
stopService(playbackServiceIntent);
```

I have alse overrided the **onDestroy()** method of the **MainActivity**:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {

            stopService(playbackServiceIntent); 
            //stopService(new Intent(this,BackgroundAudioService.class));           

            super.onDestroy();
}
```

Finally, the **BackgroundAudioService** class is defined as follow:

```
public class BackgroundAudioService extends Service implements OnCompletionListener {


public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
public WifiLock wifiLock;   
PhoneStateListener mPhoneStateListener;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {      

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();        // raw/s.mp3
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);      
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);  

    try {

        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);     

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block          
        e.printStackTrace();         
    }       

    wifiLock = ((WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE))
            .createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "mylock");

    wifiLock.acquire();             

    mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {                    

        }
    });


    mPhoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener()
    {
        protected boolean mWasPlayingWhenCalled = false;

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
        {
            if( state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING )
            { // Incoming call: Pause music

                mediaPlayer.pause();
                mWasPlayingWhenCalled = true;
            }

            else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE )
            {  // Not in call: Play music
                if( mWasPlayingWhenCalled )
                {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    mWasPlayingWhenCalled = false;                  
                }
            }
            else if( state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK )
            { // A call is dialing, active or on hold

                mediaPlayer.pause();
                mWasPlayingWhenCalled = true;                   
            }                   

            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };      


    TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    mgr.listen(mPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {      

    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {             

        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.start();

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction("com.my_app.CUSTOM_INTENT");
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        });

        Time t=new Time();
        t.setToNow();   
    }

    return START_STICKY;        
}

public void onDestroy() {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();     
    }
    wifiLock.release();
    mediaPlayer.release();      


    TelephonyManager mgr1 = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if(mgr1 != null) {
        mgr1.listen(mPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }       

    Time t=new Time();
    t.setToNow();           
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer) {
    stopSelf();
    Time t=new Time();
    t.setToNow();       
}

}
```

Comment: Without code no one can understand your problem so please post your code to know your problem.

Comment: I have updated my post. Now you can find the relevant code to my problem.